# Computing volume of an ellipsoid with a cone about its major axis removed?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

Let $E$ be an $n$-dimensional ellipsoid in $\mathbb{R}^n$ centered at $0$, and let $C$ be the cone formed by the set of all points within angle $\alpha$ of the major axis of $E$.

How can one compute the volume of $E\setminus C$?

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a stab at the 3D case. In outline only:

Given polar angles $\theta$ and $\phi$ determine a direction in 3D, and therefore a "ray" emanating from the origin. You can find the point of intersection of this ray with the ellipsoid, and therefore the length of the piece of it inside the ellipsoid. Integrate this length over $0 \le \theta  \le \alpha$ and $0 \le \phi \le 2\pi$.

Comment: 3d case is not so bad and specific equations for the cone are also not bad in this case